# How to deploy a Java web application with Travis CI to an OpenShift WildFly server?

Tags: continuous-integration, openshift, travis-ci, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

I want to deploy my web app from GitHub with Travis CI to my WildFly application server on OpenShift.

I followed the [How to Build and Deploy OpenShift Java Projects using Travis CI](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-and-deploy-openshift-java-projects-using-travis-ci/) tutorial but my `index.html` page from my Java EE 7 web app does not show up. Instead of the `index.html` page I get OpenShift's default page, saying: "Welcome to your WildFly 8 application on OpenShift".

What do I have to do so that my webapp is displayed?

Here are the last lines of my Travis CI console log:

```
remote: [WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 20db7c5e
remote: Activating deployment
remote: HAProxy already running
remote: HAProxy instance is started
remote: Deploying WildFly
remote: ls: cannot access /var/lib/openshift/54e7963efcf933b7e2000037/app-root/runtime/repo//deployments: No such file or directory
remote: Starting wildfly cart
remote: Found 127.9.239.1:8080 listening port
remote: Found 127.9.239.1:9990 listening port
remote: /var/lib/openshift/54e7963efcf933b7e2000037/wildfly/standalone/deployments /var/lib/openshift/54e7963efcf933b7e2000037/wildfly
remote: /var/lib/openshift/54e7963efcf933b7e2000037/wildfly
remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifacts deployed: ./ROOT.war
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

You can check my webapp code here: https://github.com/welovecoding/javeasy

The deployment can be seen on: http://www.javeasy.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found the problem.** I had not defined the `openshift` profile in my `pom.xml`. Declaring the `openshift` profile solved my issue.

Here is my pom.xml as reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.javeasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>javeasy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>javeasy</name>

  <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.executable>${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_DIR}usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac</maven.compiler.executable>
    <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
      <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
      <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
      <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
      <id>openshift</id>
      <build>
        <finalName>jbosswildfly</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
              <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
              <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And here is my **.travis.yml**:

```
# http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/
sudo: false

# http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

# http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/openshift/
deploy:
  provider: openshift
  user: me@mail.com
  password:
    secure: ...=
  app: jbosswildfly
  domain: welovecoding
  on:
    repo: welovecoding/javeasy
```

Application URL is: `jbosswildfly-welovecoding.rhcloud.com`

And GitHub repo is: `https://github.com/welovecoding/javeasy`

The `.travis.yml` has been created with the [Travis command line client](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2013-01-14-new-client/) using these commands:

```
travis login
travis setup openshift -r welovecoding/javeasy
```

The parameter `-r` defines the GitHub repository.